# One button to select 1 of 4 relays, the same button to activate the relay selected

Tags: arduino

I would like to be able to control four relays with one button.
(This is for a disabled friend that has very limited mobility, this will control his living room recliner chair.)

I would like to be able to push the button one, two, three or four times to choose which relay will be activated. After a short pause, pressing the same button should activate the selected relay.

So, pressing the button twice would cause an LED to blink twice, then a short pause, then blink twice again etc. to indicate that relay #2 is "selected".  Once that condition is met, pressing the same button again would activate that relay for the duration of time that the button is held down.  Once the button is released, the program should go back to looping looking for the button to be pressed again to select a different relay.

I have mashed a few bits of code together and have this partially working.  The problems start when I try to push the button to activate the relay, the variable `PushButtonCounter` increments and thinks I selected the next relay when in fact, I want to activate the previously selected relay.

How do I address that problem?

(I know my code is ugly and doesn't follow accepted C coding practices.
I am also probably leaving out a pile of important information.  There are probably better ways to code the blocks of code I have listed below.)

Additional Info:
I removed the `unsigned long` as suggested, the code still works up to the point of breaking out of the loop and activating the selected relay.  After three button presses for example, the value stored in `PushButtonCounter` is "3", as it should be. This is evaluated in the `switch` statement and drops to `case 3:`. The LED blinks as I want it to, three quick blinks, then a pause, three quick blinks, then a pause. This cycles through the loop as I expect it to. BUT, the next thing to do is press and hold the button to activate the number three relay. Instead what happens is the `PushButtonCounter` is now set to "4" and the `switch` statement now evaluates to `case 4:`. I need to somehow set `PushButtonCounter` to be "sticky" after a short bit of time, say no more than ten seconds and to not change, so when I next press the button, it is detected as "activate the selected relay for the duration of time that the button is held". Once the button is released, the program should go back to the start of the loop and wait for more button presses to select a new relay to activate.

```
// Constant values that won't change.
  const int Relay_1 = 2;
  const int Relay_2 = 3;
  const int Relay_3 = 4;
  const int Relay_4 = 5;
  const int LED = 6;
  const int PushButton = 7;

// Variable values that will change.
  int PushButtonCounter = 0;           // Counter for the number of push button presses.
  int CurrentButtonState = 0;          // Current state of the push button.
  int LastButtonState = 0;             // Previous state of the push button.
  unsigned long ButtonPressed;

void setup()
  {
    pinMode(Relay_1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Relay_2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Relay_3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Relay_4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(PushButton, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(Relay_1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Relay_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Relay_3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Relay_4, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }

void loop()
  {
    CurrentButtonState = digitalRead(PushButton);        // Read the push button input pin.
    if (CurrentButtonState != LastButtonState)           // Compare the PushButtonState to its previous state.
      {
        if (CurrentButtonState == HIGH)                  // If the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on.
          {
            ButtonPressed = millis();
            PushButtonCounter++;                         // If the state has changed, increment the counter.
          }
        delay(50);                                       // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing.
      }
    LastButtonState = CurrentButtonState;                // Save the current state as the last state for next time through the loop.
    if (PushButtonCounter == 5) PushButtonCounter = 0;
    if (millis() > ButtonPressed + 2000)
      {
         switch (PushButtonCounter)
          {
            case 1:
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
            break;
            case 2:
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
            break;  
            case 3:
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);              
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
            break;  
            case 4:
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
              delay(500);
              digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
              delay(100);
              digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
            break;
          }
        ButtonPressed = millis();  
      }
  }
```

Comment: To begin with, the value got `unsigned long ButtonPressed = millis();` will be throwed away on leaving this block. Don't define `ButtonPressed` here and use the global one.

Comment: I wonder if turning on and off the pins that control relays so quickly is really good. won't ust turning on after `case n:` and turning off after the while loop work?

Comment: I posted a better version of the code, that section that was turning the relays on then off was bogus. Sorry for the confusion. The activation of one of the four relays MUST be under control of the user, not a timed event. Timing the relay activation event could result in not reclining back far enough, or reclining to far forward.

Comment: Your code still has the unsigned long ButtonPressed = millis(); part as well as I do not see the relay activation part.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need the `unsigned long ButtonPressed = millis();` part. 
The relay activation section is what I don't know how to get working.  The code that is posted so far works exactly as I want it to.

Comment: I cleaned up a few things, please see the Additional Info in the main post for more information.